# Sass function explanation

Tags: sass

### Heading

```
@function min($numbers...) {
  $min: null;

  @each $number in $numbers {
    @if (type-of($number) != 'number') {
      @error '${number} is not a number for `min`.';
    }

    @if (not $min or $number < $min) {
      $min: $number;
    }
  }

  @return $min;
}

.test {
  foo: min( 5, 13, 2, 1, 6, 6.3, 10, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will help a bit. I have gone over the important lines with some comments:

```
@function min($numbers...) { // Function that take an argument list that can be of any length. See link below!
  $min: null; // Set the minimum value to null

  @each $number in $numbers { // Loop through all values passed as argument
    @if (type-of($number) != 'number') { // Check if value is number
      @error '${number} is not a number for `min`.'; // Raise error if it's not
    }

    @if (not $min or $number < $min) { // Check if min is null or if the current number is smaller than min
       // the not $min is here to catch a potential issue where $numbers can't be compared to null so it just sets the value as the first number it comes across
      $min: $number; // Set the value of min to the new smaller number
    }
  }

  @return $min; // return the final value of min which will be the smallest number
}

.test {
  foo: min( 5, 13, 2, 1, 6, 6.3, 10, 1); // Pass a list of numbers to the function
}
```

For more about arglists see: https://www.sitepoint.com/sass-multiple-arguments-lists-or-arglist/

Comment: This is good explanation, but can i get more specific answer about iteration, for example above..

Answer (score 0):

1. check if the number is a number - not sure how sass handles e.g. 6.1 as float or as string... nvm
2. if variable min is jet undefined, set the current number to min OR if the current number is smaller than the current min then set that to min

so in the end if you have only entered numbers, you get the smallest number of these.